# MPMoviePlayerViewController crashes on OS 3.0

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

During the testing of my app i discovered that it crashed on an iphone with OS 3.0.1 and 3.1.1(iPod Touch).

I have the following code for playing the video which is placed on a remote server. It works flawlessly on the iOS 4.0 and iPad with OS 3.2

Xcode is setup to use SDK 4.0 but target OS is 3.0.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL  URLWithString:selectedLink];  
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url]; 
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
[moviePlayer release];
```

When run on 3.0.1 and 3.1.1 I receive the following error:

```
-[UIViewController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x231550
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:  -[UIViewController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x231550'
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MPMoviePlayerViewController has been added recently and is available in iPhone OS 3.2 and later.

You should use MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: solved it by using:
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:)]) { // The new way of playing movies }
else { // The old way of playing movies }

Comment: Fantastic! OK, possibly ignorant followup question coming up here, and I think it's related to this test objneodude just shared:

I know I can check selectors, and that's great and all, BUT is there a way for me to check if a _Class_ is supported? For example, given an app with a base SDK of 4.0, but can be run on 3.0+, it's possible to alloc/init a MPMoviePlayerViewController. (It will also not work, but you can instantiate it!)

Perhaps the only sanity check is to test for properties on that class? I could look at SDK versions, but I sense it isn't always wise to do that. Thoughts?